# C# Sending data to an elementHost

Tags: c#, wpf, elementhost

Basically I have a WPF elementHost contained in my C# Windows Form. The element host needs to retrieve a variable from the Windows form, but I have found no simple way to communicate between the two of them. Is there any method in particular I should be looking out for?

I've tried the standard

```
Textbox.Text = form2.Variable;
```

But this doesn't seem to work within the WPF elementhost.

Sorry for the vagueness! I just don't know where to start!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried so far? please provide some code, approaches or where you failed otherwise we wont be able to help you

Comment: I've tried something along the lines of ----
Box.Text = form2.Variable; ---
But this doesn't seem to work with the WPF elementHost

Comment: You will need to put your code in the question and explain more about what you are trying to do. Your question is too vague to offer much help.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, In your wpf class declare a public method which returns a value

```
 //in your wpf class (class of your screen)
    public string GetTextBoxText()
    {
        return myTextBox.Text;
    }
```

In your winforms, in your winforms you can access to this method as :

```
  MyWpfApp myApp = new MyWpfApp();
  var text = myApp.SetTextBoxText();
```

Or you can declare a public property in your wpf class to get or set the textbox value.

```
    public string MyValue
    {
        get
        {
            return myTextBox.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            myTextBox.Text = value;
        }
    }


    MyWpfApp myApp = new MyWpfApp();
    var text = myApp.MyValue;
```

Comment: I'll have a go at this! Thank you!